# What prepositions does ‘are concerned’ take?

Tags: idioms, prepositions, passive-voice, comparisons

What is the most appropriate preposition to go with the verb phrase *are concerned* in the following sentence from some test or homework?

> Although ballet and modern dance are both *concerned* [ *in* / *to* / *with* / *for* / *by* / *about* ] movement in space to musical accompaniment, the training for ballet is more rigorous than that for modern dance.

Comment: _Concerned with_ is an idiom that, when referring to an artistic or academic field of activity, identifies the subject of study or activity - ballet and modern dance both involve these activities. The difference is in the training, not the area.